# How to make lambda to extract all ids which belongs to year for example 1, 3, 5?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have vector of pairs  where first in pair is id and second is year of study 
like

```
vector< pairs<uint64_t, int>> students;
```

How to make lambda to extract all ids which belongs to year for example 1, 3, 5 ?
I solved this through iteration but I wonder if I can in c++11 make this simpler.

Comment: It sounds like you want a hash table of some sort (e.g. `unordered_map`)

Comment: @PaolaJ. It is totally unclear post. Firest of all what do you mean by "extract@? Secondly What are "1,3, 5, 7|? And at last I think you should at first learn how to speak using the human language before learning the programming.

Comment: @Vlad: Coming from you...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the algorithm `std::copy_if` to copy elements to another container, if they match a certain criteria.

```
using entry = std::pair<uint64_t, int>;
std::vector<entry> result;
std::copy_if(students.begin(), students.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
    [](const entry& e) { return e.second == 1; });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've included two approaches.

The first one uses `for_each` with a lambda which uses a regular if statement to find specific keys. `copy_if` is a good substitute if that's what you want to do with your findings. It has the same approach as `for_each`.

The second approach uses an `unordered_map` to enable associative (fast) lookup with keys.

With the information you gave it sounds like you should go with the map approach. Don't overcomplicate things.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector< pair<int, int>> v;
    v.emplace_back(1,2);
    v.emplace_back(3,4);
    v.emplace_back(5,6);

    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),[](pair<int,int> p) { 
        cout << "checking key " << p.first << endl;
        if (p.first == 1 || p.first == 5) { // look for key 1 and 5
            cout << "   found a key I was looking for:  " 
            << p.first << "," << p.second << endl; 
        } 
    });

    unordered_map<int,int> m;

    m.emplace(1,2);
    m.insert(make_pair(3,4));
    m.insert(make_pair(5,10));

    cout << "value for key 5 is: " << m[5] << endl;
}
```